# How can I install pycrypto on a 64-bit Windows 7 machine?

Tags: python, windows, pip, pycrypto

I tried installing PyCrypto using `pip`, but it complained about needing vcvarsall.bat.  I installed Visual Studio 2008, but now I get `ValueError: [u'path']` when I try to install it from `pip`.

I tried downloading a pre-built binary from [Voidspace](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml#pycrypto), but they only have 32-bit versions, and it doesn't seem to install correctly on my machine (it says it succeeded, but running python and trying `import Crypto` gives me an `ImportError: No module named Crypto`).

What do I need to do?

Comment: [Relevant](http://bugs.python.org/issue7511)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Voidspace](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml#pycrypto) now has prebuilt 64bit binaries:

eg. [The 64bit binary for python 2.7](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/downloads/pycrypto26/pycrypto-2.6.win-amd64-py2.7.exe)