# How to install pycrypto in a Windows Vista64 virualenv created with PyCharm 4

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv, pycharm

I created a virtualenv with PyCharm 4 on a Windows Vista 64 machine.  I'm new to this type of setup on Windows.

On Ubuntu I would just type source bin/activate.  I tried that and it doesn't work.

I am having trouble:

- Activating the PyCharm created VirtualEnv on Windows
- Installing the [Python 2.7 64-bit version of Pycrypto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10708538/how-can-i-install-pycrypto-on-a-64-bit-windows-7-machine) in the VirtualEnv only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Navigate to the `Scripts` folder inside your virtual environment.
2. Activate the environment by entering `activate.bat`
3. Download the 64bit version of pycrypto [found here](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml#pycrypto)
4. Copy the pycrypto `.exe` file to the `Scripts` folder of your virtual environment.
5. Install it by entering `easy_install <name_of_your_pycrypto_install_file>.exe`

The answer was found by looking at a psycopg 64 virtualenv install instructions: http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/